# Android Service notification

Tags: android, service, notifications

I got a problem with a service: I'd like to create a notification that say to the user that there's no location provider, this is my code:

```
Notification notificationNoProvider = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, message, System.currentTimeMillis());

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notificationNoProvider.setLatestEventInfo(this,message,message, pendingIntent);

notificationManager.notify(message.hashCode(), notificationNoProvider);
```

The application gives me a NullPointerException in the getActivity method of PendingIntent.
I tryed also with getApplicationContext instead of geBasecontext but the application still explode.
I've found that the problem is at this line of getActivity:

```
public static PendingIntent  [Search] getActivity(Context context, int requestCode,Intent intent, int flags) {
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();//here the application explodes
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about calling:

```
startForeground(id, notification);
```

from your service?